# В чем ошибка кода (emu8086)

Tags: ассемблер, emu8086

Есть пример кода:

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h
begin:
mov ah, 9
mov dx, offset message
int 21h
ret
mov dx, offset message1
int 21h
int 20h
message db "Hello", 0dh, 0ah, '$'
message1 db "Group", 0dh, 0ah, '$'
end begin
```

Только начал разбираться с кодом и уже не работает, прога компилируется, но не пойму в чем ошибка. Выводит только "Hello".

Comment: есть сомнения насчет ret

Comment: @EvgenyShmidt, вы были. правы, удалил его и ве заработало. но не совсем понял. насколько я понимаю, он завершает программу? но в то же время int 20h делает тоже самое?

Comment: Ага, а еще функция 4c прерывания 21 то же завершает программу. способов завершить программу много. А `ret` производит просто выход из функции, т.е. производит переход по адресу из стека, а в момент запуска программы в стеке находится адрес инструкции завершающей программу

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за ответ